# My Strlen Syntax Not Written Well?

Tags: c

if I write more than 20 charcters in my program it runs through it and skips my if statement if(length > 20). What did I do wrong?

```
printf("\nEnter Your Product:");
fgets(item_name, 20, stdin);

length = strlen(item_name);
if(length > 20){
    Errorlevel("Input Greater Than 20");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at what the `20` is doing in the `fgets` call.

Comment: You told `fgets` to read no more than 19 characters of input, even if you type more.  Are you maybe looking for [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) instead?

Comment: You are limitting the input to 20 in `fgets`,, how it can be more then 20?

Answer (score 1):

You set fgets to gather a maximum of 20 chars. Thus, `if(length > 20)` is always false.

See [documentation about fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Answer (score 1):

The `fgets` will read up the the requested number of character ***minus one***. The size you pass to the `fgets` function *includes the terminator*.

So no matter how many characters you write, the length will never be longer than 19 characters.

A simple way to check if to many characters were input is to see if the last character (not the string terminator) is a newline or not. If it's not then 19 or more characters were entered as input.